# Windows Azure - how do you change the region of a Table Storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, regions

I've created a Hosted Service that talks to a Storage Account in Azure. Both have their regions set to Anywhere US but looking at the bills for the last couple of months I've found that I'm being charged for communication between the two as one is in North-Central US and the other South-Central US.

Am I correct in thinking there would be no charge if they were both hosted in the same sub-region?

If so, is it possible to move one of them and how do I go about doing it? I can't see anywhere in the Management Portal that allows me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what astaykov said: My advice is to always select a specific region, even if you don't  use affinity groups. You'll now be assured that your storage and services are in the same data center and you won't incur outbound bandwidth charges.

There isn't a way to move a storage account; you'll need to either transfer your data (and incur bandwidth costs), or re-deploy your hosted service to the region currently hosting your data (no bandwidth costs). To minimize downtime if your site is live, you can push your new hosted service up (to a new .cloudapp.net name), then change your DNS information to point to the new hosted service.

EDIT 5/23/2012 - If you re-visit the portal and create a new storage account or hosted service, you'll notice that the Anywhere options are no longer available. This doesn't impact existing accounts (although they'll now be shown at their current subregion).

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid such charges the best guideline is to use Affinity Groups. You define affinity group once, and then choose it when creating new storage account or hosted service. You can still have the Affinity Group in "Anywhere US", but as long as both the storage account and the hosted service are in the same affinity group, they will be placed in one DataCenter.

As for moving account from one region to another - I don't think it is possible. You might have to create a new account and migrate the data if required. You can use some 3rd party tool as [Cerebrata's Cloud Storage Studio](http://cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/) to first export your data and then import it into the new account.

Don't forget - use affinity groups! This is the way to make 100% sure there will no be traffic charges between Compute, Storage, SQL Azure.

Comment: Using affinity groups is a very good idea, but while you can choose "Anywhere US", based on my experience, don't.  Affinity groups only apply to roles and storage.  If you want to use SQL Azure or service bus you still have to choose a specific data centre and not an affinity group.  If you use one of the "Anywhere..." regions then you don't know where to locate those other services without contacting MS support.

Comment: You are completly right for the SQL Azure & Service Bus, that they don't have the affinity group option to choose. Though I think its kind of current limitation and should be fixed. So at the end, one can still has an affinity group pointing to a specific data center, and use that data center for SQL Azure and Service Bus.

Comment: Exactly, use an affinity group, but know which data centre it's pointing to.  I'm not sure how much of a hurry MS are in to add affinity groups to SQL and SB.